# How to Create a 3 Level List in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists

How to I create a 3 level list in python 2.7?  [See Image of Nested Lists HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO1xQ.png)

Setup:
I have the following inputs:

1. Files(s)
2. Categories

I then Search through each file, and iterate through each category to get every Value.

I just can't get the desired output.

```
# Combine Multiple Lists
LinkDoc = ["File1", "File2", "File3"]
cat = ["Walls", "Doors", "Columns"]
rvt1_wall = ["W1_rvt1", "W2_rvt1"]
rvt1_door = ["D1_rvt1", "D2_rvt1", "D3_rvt1", "D4_rvt1"]
rvt1_col = ["C1_rvt1"]
rvt2_wall = ["W2_rvt2", "W2_rvt2"]
rvt2_door = ["D2_rvt2", "D2_rvt2", "D3_rvt2", "D4_rvt2"]
rvt2_col = ["C2_rvt2"]
rvt3_wall = ["W3_rvt3", "W2_rvt3"]
rvt3_door = ["D3_rvt3", "D2_rvt3", "D3_rvt3", "D4_rvt3"]
rvt3_col = ["C3_rvt3"]
rvt4_wall = ["W4_rvt4", "W2_rvt4"]
rvt4_door = ["D4_rvt4", "D2_rvt4", "D3_rvt4", "D4_rvt4"]
rvt4_col = ["C4_rvt4"]

all_comb1 = [rvt1_wall,rvt1_door,rvt1_col]
all_comb2 = [rvt2_wall,rvt2_door,rvt2_col]
all_comb3 = [rvt3_wall,rvt3_door,rvt3_col]
all_comb4 = [rvt4_wall,rvt4_door,rvt4_col]
all_tot = [all_comb1, all_comb2, all_comb3, all_comb4]

xyz_pairs = [[x,y,z] for x in LinkDoc for y in cat for z in all_tot]
print(xyz_pairs)
print("========")

print("")
```

Comment: Post your code and explain what works and what does not work in the code you tried so far.

Comment: Like this??? ```[[File1[cat1],[cat2],[cat3],[cat4]],[File2[cat1],[cat2],[cat3],[cat4]]]```

Comment: Maybe a dictionary would be a better choice?

Comment: Code posted above.  I'm getting `[['File1', 'Walls', [['W1_rvt1', 'W2_rvt1'], ['D1_rvt1', 'D2_rvt1', 'D3_rvt1', 'D4_rvt1']...`

Comment: I'm trying to get ' something like the image I posted in link above or `[[File1[cat1[val1],[val2]],[cat2[val1],[val2]]],[File2[cat1[val1],[val2]],[cat2[val1],[val2]]]]' I think`

Comment: I don't know enough about python to know if I should be using Dictionaries, vs List Comprehension vs For Loops.  Everyone seems to have different opinions.   Anyone have a a phrase I should be googling to find what I'm after?

Comment: Work your way through [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples that are given.  It will help you get ideas.  You might want to stick with for loops and leave comprehensions for later.  You can put print statements/functions in a for loop to show you what is happening  as the loop progresses.